# Differential Equations applications in Computer Science

Tags: reference-request, applications, differential

I'm writing a project on differential equations and their applications on several scientific fields (such as electrical circuits, polulation dynamics, oscillations etc) but i'm mainly interested in DE applications on Informatics/Computer Science, so i'm looking for help on what and how to search, or any possible e-book that could help me.

Answer (score 1):

You will not find as much examples as in physics or engineering because differential equations model continous quantities, while a large part of computer science deals with discrete quantities and structures.

The related methods like difference equations / recurrences and Diophantine equations are used.

Answer (score 0):

in comupter science neural networks (artificial intelligence) , 
[Lagrange multipliers](https://darkcornerlaboratory.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/intelligent-app-stores-using-artificial-neural-networks/) are always used to optimize and maximize the functions of neural networks.

gradient decent methods are used in Back propagation for fitting an artificial neural network. these are two examples I can think of.

almost all of machine learning and AI(svm ,regressions trees) are filled with examples of differential equations. The list could go endless.